# Determining which item was clicked from another class

Tags: android, bundle, viewflipper

I have a List class and a Viewflipper class, how can I know which Item was clicked from the List class in the Viewflipper class and if it's possible, I also want to link each view to a specific view of a Viewflipper. This is what I have tried so far:

List class:

```
public class List extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] service_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.List);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, R.id.list, service_list));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
     //Toast.makeText(this, "you have clicked " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent i = new Intent(List.this, Viewflipper.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("a", "apple");
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case 1:
        Intent a = new Intent(List.this, Viewflipper.class);
        Bundle aa = new Bundle();
        aa.putString("b", "banana");
        a.putExtras(aa);
        startActivity(a);

        break;

    case 2:
        Intent ab = new Intent(List.this, Viewflipper.class);
        Bundle bb = new Bundle();
        bb.putString("m", "mango");
        ab.putExtras(bb);
        startActivityForResult(ab, 2);
        break;

    case 3:
        Intent c = new Intent(List.this, Viewflipper.class);
        Bundle cc = new Bundle();
        cc.putString("o", "orange");
        c.putExtras(cc);
        startActivity(c);
         break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
}
}
```

ViewFlipper Class:

```
      public class Viewflipper extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
      OnGestureListener {

private ViewFlipper viewflipper;
private Button btnNext, btnPrevious;
private GestureDetector gesturedetector = null;

TextView txt;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewflipper);

    viewflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);

    txt.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);

    gesturedetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {



        if (bundle.getString("a").equals("apple")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, " the first Item was clicked ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (bundle.getString("b").equals("banana")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "the second Item was clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (bundle.getString("m").equals("mango")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "the fourth Item was clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (bundle.getString("o").equals("orange")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "the fifth Item was clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else {


        } // Toast.makeText(this, b , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
    }
}
// Animation
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnNext:
        // Button Next Style
        Animation animationNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.btn_style_next);
        btnNext.startAnimation(animationNext);

        nextView();
        break;

    case R.id.btnPrevious:
        // Button Previous Style
        Animation animationPrevious = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.btn_style_previous);
        btnPrevious.startAnimation(animationPrevious);

        previousView();
        break;

    case R.id.txtview:
        Toast.makeText(this, "dail contact or visit website",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

int SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY = 100;
int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;

// Sự kiện khi bạn vuốt màn hình đưa sang một bên nào đó
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // Get Position
    float ev1X = e1.getX();
    float ev2X = e2.getX();

    // Get distance of X (e1) to X (e2)
    final float xdistance = Math.abs(ev1X - ev2X);
    // Get veclocity of cusor
    // Vận tốc = số điểm ảnh (px) / giây
    final float xvelocity = Math.abs(velocityX);

    // Vận tốc chuyển đổi X > 100 và khoảng cách từ điểm kéo đầu đến điểm
    // kéo cuối > 100
    if ((xvelocity > SWIPE_MIN_VELOCITY)
            && (xdistance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)) {
        if (ev1X > ev2X)// Switch Left
        {
            previousView();
        } else// Switch Right
        {
            nextView();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

// Next, Previous Views
private void previousView() {

    // Previous View
    viewflipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation1);
    viewflipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation1);
    viewflipper.showPrevious();

}

private void nextView() {

    // Next View
    viewflipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation);
    viewflipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation);
    viewflipper.showNext();

}

}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend changing the `List` code so it is like this:

```
switch (position) {
Intent i = new Intent(List.this, Viewflipper.class);
case 0:
    i.putExtra ("key", "apple");
    startActivity(i);
    break;

case 1:
    i.putExtra ("key", "banana");
    startActivity(i);
    break;

case 2:
    i.putExtra ("key", "mango");
    startActivity(i);
    break;

case 3:
    i.putExtra ("key", "orange");
    startActivity(i);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Then in `Viewflipper`, change your code so it is like this:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("key")) {

String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra ("key");

    if ("apple".equals (extra)){
        Toast.makeText(this, " the first Item was clicked ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if ("banana".equals (extra)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "the second Item was clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if  ("mango".equals (extra)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "the fourth Item was clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "the fifth Item was clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What I changed:

- Declared the `Intent` at beginning of the switch, to save some code.
- Made it so that the extra passed always has the same key. What you were doing before (one separate key for each case doesn't work that well, you can get NPEs and it defeats the point of a key-value pair.
- Did away with the Bundle, since it is redundant. `Intent#putExtra()` and `Intent#getStringExtra()` are fine.
- Did `"string".equals (stringVariable)` since `String#equals()` method can handle `null` values without throwing an `NPE`.

Comment: @Brianmuks no problem! You should try this out and see if it resolves some of your issues. One thing I did edit (since this is all being done from memory): `getIntent().hasExtra("key"))` is proper. `hasExtras()` doesn't exist.

Comment: no errors now the app is working perfectly, thanks for the explanation, I was wondering why my code was not working.

Comment: @Brianmuks since you said that your app is now working perfectly, you should mark this answer as accepted so future visitors can easily see what worked for you.